# Dynamically add view with LayoutParams

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, layoutparams

I want to add an `ImageView` on `LinearLayout` with specific `LayoutParams`.

When I use an `ImageView` which is defined in `dot_layout.xml`, the `layoutParams` works fine (Commented line). However, when I dynamically created and add `ImageView` with layout parameters (in for loop), `leftMargin` doesn't work.

```
public void addDots() {
    LinearLayout dotLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dot_layout);
    dotLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();

    //ImageView dotImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.slider_dot);
    //LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) dotImage.getLayoutParams();
    //layoutParams.leftMargin = 100;
    //dotImage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    for(int i=0; i<INTERVAL; i++) {
        ImageView dot = new ImageView(mContext);
        dot.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.slider_dot));

        LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.leftMargin = (int) ((i*mLengthOfSlider/INTERVAL)*mDensity);

        dotLayout.addView(dot, layoutParams);
    }

}
```

Here's my dot_layout.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dot_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/slider_dot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/slider_dot"
     />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I was expecting a view with dot images like : `*      *      *      *`

but I'm getting : `****` (which has no left margin)

What am I doing wrong here? Can anyone help me?

Comment: are you sure you set `mLengthOfSlider` and `mDensity` previously? Looks like one of them is 0.

Comment: Oh yeap, I set those two in another function, and values are not zero.

Comment: i am not sure if hierarchyviewer shows layout params but you can give it a try

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
```

and to add an ImageButton

```
 ImageButton myButton = new ImageButton(this);
 myButton.setBackgroundDrawable(demoCoverImage);
 LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(70, 60);
 ll.addView(myButton, lp);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is basically same code as mine. Problem not being solved.